# Draw the knobs and controls of oven in latex

Tags: diagrams

I want to draw a graphical picture of the control of oven for my cooking video.
Here is an example of them. https://www.agefotostock.com/age/en/details-photo/collection-of-different-oven-temperatures-with-analog-display-and-a-set-of-icons/ESY-056881603
Does anybody can provide a link or hint to start?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please read the [introductory material](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Unfortunately, your question does not meet the standards for this site. You might consider learning about `TikZ`, for example by reading the [Minimal Introduction](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en) on CTAN. Then make an attempt at your diagram and post a new question with a more specific request.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.